# How to add Password encoder to authentication-provider in Spring 5

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to add a password encoder to authentication-provider which references UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper but i do not find any information in Spring Docs on  how to add a nooppassword encoder or BCryptPasswordEncoder.

Can you please me understand where can i add the bCryptPasswordEncoder in xml configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You have wired the `bCryptPasswordEncoder` correctly. Now, don't use `UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper`.

Make your class `CustomUserDetailsService` to implement [`AuthenticationUserDetailsService`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/cas/userdetails/GrantedAuthorityFromAssertionAttributesUserDetailsService.html) instead.

```
<bean id="preauthAuthProviderRest" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService" 
              ref="com.hp.ci.mgmt.security.sprsec.CustomUserDetailsService" />
</bean>
```

Comment: I have pasted the code for CustomUserDetailsService above, please let me know how to implement AuthenticationUserDetailsService.

Answer (score 0):

In my spring-security.xml, I have done these following configurations:

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider ref="authenticationProvider" />
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="authenticationProvider" class="com.sc.auth.LimitLoginAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="passwordEncoder" ref="encoder" />
    <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="customUserDetailsService" />
    <beans:property name="userDetailsManager" ref="userDetailsManager" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="strength" value="10" />
</beans:bean>
```

My com.sc.auth.LimitLoginAuthenticationProvider class extends org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;.

DaoAuthenticationProvider needs field org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PasswordEncoder; as a parameter which I have provided through property injection while defining bean with id="authenticationProvider"

Please try this. Hope this helps!!

Comment: Hi Abhishesk, i tried this but i am getting below error. Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'passwordEncoder' of bean class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider]: Bean property 'passwordEncoder' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?